# Getting Java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException

Tags: java, classcastexception, linkageerror

Trying to run my flex project and I get the below error , 
Please suggest any way forward :-

Caused by:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/software/bea/java/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.class to zip:/wls_domains/abct22/servers/managed13_abct22/tmp/_WL_user/xyz/2o9q1y/war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-api.jar!/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.class
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:94)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at com.oracle.xmlns.communications.ordermanagement.OrderManagementService.<init>(OrderManagementService.java:71)
    at com.df.abc.action.np.npAction.omsWebSerCall(npAction.java:3741)
    at com.df.abc.action.np.npAction.omsWebServiceCall(npAction.java:3683)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: There are two classes `Provider` with same name in different jars(rt.jar and jaxws-api.jar), now somewhere in your code, you assigned the rt jar's `Provider` class object to jaxws-api.jar's `Provider` class reference or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You have two versions of the same jar on the classpath. The error mean that you have an object created from one jar which the code tries to cast to the other jar, which doesn’t work.

This is not an uncommon problem.

Revise your deployment not to include the jaxws-api.jar as long as you are still deploying to a Java 8 server.